# How do I change the 'x' and 'y' of a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I create a canvas I can only change the width and height. What piece of code would I use to change the x and y position of the canvas?

Look how far left it is how do I make it more in the middle?

I have tried adding x and y to the canvas but to no avail.

Here is some of the code I uses for the canvas.

```html
<html>
<canvas id="ctx" width="250" height="250" style="border:5px solid #000000"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '50px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Hello',70,135);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean body center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your canvas tag one `container(div)` and add `text-align: center`

```html
<html>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <canvas id="ctx" width="250" height="250" style="border:5px solid #000000"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '50px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Hello',70,135);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the `margin-left` CSS-property.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '50px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Hello',70,135);
```

```css
#ctx {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx" width="250" height="250" style="border:5px solid #000000"></canvas>
```

---

In order to **center** the canvas, you could use the following code:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '50px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Hello',70,135);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#canvas-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas-wrapper">
<canvas id="ctx" width="250" height="250" style="border:5px solid #000000"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<center>
    <canvas style='position:absolute;left:150px;top:5px;border:5px solid #000000' id="ctx" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
</center>
    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = '50px Arial';
    ctx.fillText('Hello',70,135);
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think you accidentally removed the border by adding a new inline style.

Comment: Thought I would throw it in to see who's paying attention